# SVProgressHUD with CocoaPods different version

Tags: ios, progress-bar, version, cocoapods

I'm trying to use the library [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) with CocoaPods

```
$ cat Podfile
platform :ios
...
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 0.8.1'
```

It's working fine but I saw certain functions not available like `showProgress`
And checking the .m file I actually don't see the corresponding implementation.

`0.8.1` is the latest version of this library.

How can this be explained ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [tags](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/tags) of SVProgressHUD the `0.8.1` tag was made over 3 months ago. But if you look at the [commits](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/commits/master) there have been about 50 since then.

You have two options for how to deal with this. You can either ask Sam to add a new tag and submit a new version to Cocoapods, which is helpful for everyone.

Or if you need an immediate fix instead of defining the pod in your `Podfile` with

```
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 0.8.1'
```

You can use:

```
pod 'SVProgressHUD', :head
```

Which will pull the most recent source from the git repo. BEWARE: If the repo is changed in someway that may break your code and you run a new `pod install` it will break. This is why we encourage library maintainers and users to create and use git tags.

Comment: Ho I didn't see the latest commits. Thank you, I also just saw this [issue](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/pull/127)

Comment: Also you have the `pod 'SVProgressHUD', :git => '...', :commit => '...'` to avoid having a moving target as in `:head`. It also works if you want to use a branch instead of master.